# Html tag remove using jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "x<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">3/2}</span></span></span>+y<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">7/8}</span></span></span>";
```

From this I want to print **x^{3/2}+y^{7/8}**

For this I tried like this:

```
res1=$(str).find('span').contents().unwrap().end().end();


alert(res1.html());
```

But this gives **^{3/2}** only. The x and second part is missing(`+y^{7/8}`).

How can I get the required result as `x^{3/2}+y^{7/8}`.

Please help me...

Comment: check the demo... works as advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make it a part of temporary div and then use `text` on it, which will return what you want.

```
var str = 'x<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">3/2}</span></span></span>+y<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">7/8}</span></span></span>';
console.log($('<div />').html(str).text());
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = 'x<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">3/2}</span></span></span>+y<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">7/8}</span></span></span>';
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#test').html(str).hide();
        alert(jQuery('#test').html());

    });
</script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape quotes within quotes of the same type. I just avoid them

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/f713f61bf5746f89317cedbeeffe147d)

```
var str = "x<span>^{<span style='vertical-align: 0em;'><span class='fm-vert fm-frac'>3/2}</span></span></span>+y<span>^{<span style='vertical-align: 0em;'><span class='fm-vert fm-frac'>7/8}</span></span></span>";
alert($('<div />', { html: str }).text());
```

i also do this sometimes to keep html strings readable:

```
var str = ["x<span>^{",
              "<span style='vertical-align: 0em;'>",
                  "<span class='fm-vert fm-frac'>3/2}</span>",
              "</span>",
           "</span>",
           "+y<span>^{",
              "<span style='vertical-align: 0em;'>",
                  "<span class='fm-vert fm-frac'>7/8}</span>",
              "</span>",
           "</span>"].join('');

alert($('<div />', { html: str }).text());
```

Comment: I dont want to print it inside a div, I need to get the required value in a javascript variable

Comment: it is inside a variable, dude. `var str = [...` remember?

Comment: in this code when I alert span is coming, I mean that!!

Comment: okie dokie. well... i was mainly pointing out that your quotations were screwy. `alert($('<div />', { html: str }).text());` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
str.replace(/<(|\/)spa[^>]*>/g, '');
```

?

```
var str = 'x<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">3/2}</span></span></span>+y<span>^{<span style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span class="fm-vert fm-frac">7/8}</span></span></span>';

console.log(str.replace(/<(|\/)span[^>]*>/g, ''));
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/m6mw4ujL/)